# How to run INSERT INTO AS SELECT in parallel on Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, parallelism

I have a very large table AUD$ that I want to copy it to another empty one with the same structure AUD_BACKUP.

```
INSERT INTO TEST_USER.AUD_BACKUP 
    SELECT * FROM SYS.AUD$;
COMMIT;
```

How do I use parallel for INSERT as well as for SELECT ?
I can afford to run in 100 parallels. I am on Oracle db 12.2.

Comment: `insert /*+ parallel (100) */ ...`?

Answer (score -1):

You should use direct path INSERT.

For select you can use PARALLEL hint in the same statement.  you may use PARALLEL without any parameter or use PARALLEL(n) **with n number of thread**.

Let me know if you need more explanation on this.

Answer (score -3):

#### Explanation

I will try to show you an example as MySql because i didn't found an online complier that could help me to run Oracle quary.

#### Code Section

**Create two tables**

```
-- table 1
CREATE TABLE table1(
    int id integer,
    title varchar(100)
);
-- table 1 backup
CREATE TABLE backup_table1(
    int id integer,
    title varchar(100)
);
```

**Insertion**

```
-- insert data into table1
INSERT INTO table1 (id, title)
VALUES (1, "hello world!");
```

```
-- table1_backup
INSERT INTO backup_table1 (id, title)
SELECT id, title FROM table1;
```

**OUTPUT**

`SELECT * FROM backup_table1;`

```
id     title
1      hello world!
```

#### REFERENCE

[SQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)